# Production/test distribution with fabric Beta and fastlane

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric, fastlane

Im trying to use beta to distribute with development and distribution provisionals.

Using different schemes.

Im using fastlane.

If i use `gym(scheme: 'xxxx', export_method: ‘development’)`

The push certificates are dev.

If i use `gym(scheme: 'xxxx', export_method: ‘app-store’)`

the app appears in the beta page but it says that the distribution is wrong.

If i use any other export_method i get a gym error.

So how do i upload the app with dev/distribution provisionals and cpush certificates?

Thanks

Comment: Great question. Todd from Fastlane/Fabric here. Can you let me know if you are using automatic or manual code signing in your build settings? Thanks!

Comment: automatic code signing, thanks @ToddBurner

Comment: @ToddBurner would love some help here, Thanks.